# Lost data binding going to a datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I am working on an app that talks to a camera, and tweaks settings and shows you the result.  It was written to alway run with the camera on its side, so all the images were in portrait mode.  Requirements change, now we need to auto-detect the orientation of the camera, and adjust the screen.  I'm not a WPF expert, but it sure sounds like a datatemplate to me.  I took a screen that was working fine, and my plan was to grab the current layout, move it to a template, then use a contentcontrol to display it, and a datatemplateselector to switch between the original portrait layout and a new landscape layout.

Step 1, and I've already been beating my head against a wall.  Here was the (excerpted) original code:
xaml:

```
<Window 
    <!-- header stuff --> 
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
  <Grid>
      <Slider Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Value="{Binding Path=ISO}"  ValueChanged="slISO_ValueChanged"/>

      <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding PreviewImage}" Height="588" Width="434"  />
  </Grid>
```

and code behind:

```
public partial class CameraSettingsWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // INotifyPropertyChanged Interface
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> selectorExpression)
    {
        if (selectorExpression == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("selectorExpression");
        var body = selectorExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (body == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("The body must be a member expression");
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(body.Member.Name));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, Expression<Func<T>> selectorExpression)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(selectorExpression);
        return true;
    }

    private int _iso;
    private BitmapSource _previewSource;


    public int ISO { get { return _iso; } set { SetField(ref _iso, value, () => ISO); } }
    public BitmapSource PreviewImage { get { return _previewSource; } private set { SetField(ref _previewSource, value, () => PreviewImage); } }

    public CameraSettingsWindow()
    {
        ISO = CanonCamera.Instance.GetISO();
        InitializeComponent();

        CanonCamera.Instance.PictureTaken += PictureTaken;
    }

    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnPreview_Click(this, null);  //load the preview control
    }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        CanonCamera.Instance.PictureTaken -= PictureTaken;
    }

    private void PictureTaken(object sender, CanonImageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var image = e.GetImage();
        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(image))
        {
            PreviewImage  = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bmp.GetHbitmap(),
                                                               IntPtr.Zero,
                                                               Int32Rect.Empty,
                                                               BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
    }
}
```

So, all I did was move the Grid into a data template, and change the main grid to include a ContentControl:

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PortraitTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

I was assuming it would pick up the data context from the main control, but on the chance that it needed some help getting there, I've tried adding a Content= parameter to the content control, but when I get as far as ="{Binding}", half the time visual studio locks up, so I've created an infinite context loop somewhere doing that.  I've also tried changing the static resource to dynamic, and I've seen some posts that suggest the currently bound controls need to have the binding changed to a relative path when they are in the data template, but I don't quite understand that, and would appreciate some pointers.  With the new style, it renders just fine, but the slider does not get set, and the pictures never load into the Image.

Comment: Remove all that code behind. `INotifyPropertyChanged` does not belong into `DependencyObject`s, which already have their own property change notification via DependencyProperties. You're mashing together completely disparate concepts. Create a proper ViewModel and move all your `INotifyPropertyChanged` based code there, and remove the `DataContext={Self}` from the Window.

Comment: So apparently the answer is, don't do that :).  If you'd like to add that as an answer instead of just a comment, I can mark it as correct.